# Splitting a text document into an excel sheet xls

Tags: python, excel, split, xlrd, xlwt

I am currently trying to export/convert a text document I have into an .xls file. So after from what i've found i was able to create an xls but now i just need to get the formatting correct in xls from the text document.

Heres an example of what I am trying to do.

Lets say I have the following text document: *numbers.txt*

```
|<DOg>|
    |Data1 = 300    |
    |Data2 = 200    |
    |Data3 = 15 |
    |Data4 = 14 |
    |Data5 = 4  |
|<DOg>|
    |Data1 = 800    |
    |Data2 = 500    |
    |Data3 = 25 |
    |Data4 = 10 |
    |Data5 = 5  |
```

if I run my code using `|` as the delimiter I receive this as the .xls file

[image: excel]

As you can see the formatting is off.

The goal am i trying to get is the following formatting instead.

[image: excelFormatted]

The current code I am using is the following:

```
mypath = raw_input("Please enter the directory path for the input files: ")

from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
textfiles = [ join(mypath,f) for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) and '.txt' in  f]

def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

import xlwt
import xlrd

style = xlwt.XFStyle()
style.num_format_str = '#,###0.00'

for textfile in textfiles:
    f = open(textfile, 'r+')
    row_list = []
    for row in f:
        row_list.append(row.split('|'))
    column_list = zip(*row_list)
    # for column_list in f:
    #     column_list.append(column.split('|'))
    workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
    worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('Sheet1')
    i = 0
    for column in column_list:
        for item in range(len(column)):
            value = column[item].strip()
            if is_number(value):
                worksheet.write(item, i, float(value), style=style)
            else:
                worksheet.write(item, i, value)
        i+=1
    workbook.save(textfile.replace('.txt', '.xls'))
```

My idea was using the `.split()` method for columns however I'm unsure how to implemented correctly since when I use `split` for columns every single  line ends up being it's own column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have unlimited columns.  You need to capture all the results in an array and transpose them as follows:

```
import re

# Strip all spaces and dump all data into an array
lines = [mo for mo in re.findall('(?s)(?<=\|)([<\w].+?)\s+?\|', open('py.txt').read())]
# Create an array to hold the transformation
combined = ['' for x in range(len(lines) / lines.count("<DOg>|"))]
# Append by rows
for idx in range(len(lines)):
  combined[idx % len(combined)] += lines[idx] + ','

# Write array to file
output = open('numbersConverted.csv','w')
for comb in combined:
  output.write(comb + "\n")
output.close
```

This will dump your results in a numbersConverted.csv ready for import.

Comment: How can i edit the line `or mo in re.findall('(?s)\|(\<DO.*?)\|.*?\|(.*?)\s+\|.*?\|(.*?)\s+\|.*?\|(.*?)\s+\|.*?\|(.*?)\s+\|.*?\|(.*?)\s+\|', all):` so that I can have an n number of different parameters? so lets say I have some parameters with 6 data lines and another one with 10 etc how can i edit this to allow me to print out every line

Comment: What do you mean 6 data lines?  The current example has 2 data lines right?

Comment: sorry when i say data lines I mean like `data1=291, data2=313,...datan=123` etc etc

Comment: I would say that would be in the extreme regex category, if at all possible.  This would involve an unlimited number of capture groups in a non-capture group, which I've not seen. I would suggest going with a parser instead, and parse until you hit the end of your file, or hit another |<DOg>|.

Comment: Okay and what if rather than having an n amount of lines for Data1 i have a large amount that isn't n infinite but rather large like maybe 200 lines?

Comment: each data element is captured in the repeating pattern .*?\|(.*?)\s+\| and I have exactly 5 of them.  I don't think you would want to do that 200 times.  Are you only doing this once? How many DOgs do you have?

Comment: around 100-200 it changes every so often but its usually in this range

Comment: Go with @LetzerWille, my solution answers your specific problem above, not a generic solution which you have now clarified.  I was trying to give a concise solution, but it will not scale.

Comment: I've updated my answer that is more concise and will scale

Comment: Thanks im going to go ahead and select this as the best answer since it's the one i've worked on the most with i have a question though how does the line `(?s)(?<=\|)([<D].+?)\s+?\|` work exactly? Im asking but i may have a parameter not start with the letter D such as `Link1=23, Data1=30`

Comment: It's just an extra check to make sure it starts with something in the [] brackets.  I've added all letters, that should help.

Answer (score 3):

If I read the question right, I guess you can convert it to a coma separated format, and hence use it as a csv file.

```
>>> for i in f.readlines():
...   print i
... 
|Data1 = 300    |

|Data2 = 200    |

|Data3 = 15 |

|Data4 = 14 |

|Data5 = 4  |

|<DOg>|

|Data1 = 800    |

|Data2 = 500    |

|Data3 = 25 |

|Data4 = 10 |

>>> f.seek(0)
for i in f.readlines():
...   if "=" in i:
...     "".join(",".join(i.split("=")).split("|")).strip()
'Data1 , 300'
'Data2 , 200'
'Data3 , 15'
'Data4 , 14'
'Data5 , 4'
'Data1 , 800'
```

You can modify your script to write it to another file, and probably format it to a perfect csv file.

Answer (score 1):

```
def convert_for_excel(data):
    import re
    with open(data, 'r') as f:
        st = ' '.join(f.readlines())
        li = [x for x in re.split(r'\s*\|',st) if x]
        # find <DOg> indices
        ind_of_dog = [i for i, x in enumerate(li) if x == '<DOg>' ]
        # break the list into sublists by indices of <DOg>
        all_lines = [ li[i:j] for i, j in zip([0]+ind_of_dog, ind_of_dog+[None]) if li[i:j]]
        # zip sublists to make tuples
        # join tuples to make Excel ready strings
        excel_ready = [','.join(t) for t in list(zip(*all_lines)) ]

        return excel_ready


pprint.pprint(convert_for_excel('data'))

['<DOg>,<DOg>',
 'Data1 = 300,Data1 = 800',
 'Data2 = 200,Data2 = 500',
 'Data3 = 15,Data3 = 25',
 'Data4 = 14,Data4 = 10',
 'Data5 = 4,Data5 = 5']
```